# Use external css or insert style tag to document fragment

Tags: javascript, css

I have document fragment which I create dynamically and send to my printer for printing.

```
var docHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();

var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = "<div>" +
                            "Some content goes here" +
                      "</div>";

docHtml.appendChild(container);
var docsToPrint = MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(docHtml);
```

1) I have problem with printing margins and I do not know/where to put my css rule:

```
@page { 
    margin:0cm;
}
```

into my document fragment ?

2) Is it possible somehow to use external css file in document fragment or  to insert 'style' tag into fragment with all css rules ?

Comment: Use an external css files with all the required rules. Then just add the class you created in your stylesheet on your javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the HTML page you are creating the `div` inside is linked to your `css` file, this should not be a problem.

Try this:

```
container.innerHTML = "<div style='margin:0;'>" +
                            "Some content goes here" +
                      "</div>";
```

or more elegant:

```
container.innerHTML = "<div class='nomargin'>" +
                            "Some content goes here" +
                      "</div>";
```

and in your css:

```
.nomargin { margin:0 }
```

Comment: I updated question with var docsToPrint = MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(docHtml);  Actually this fragment is whole my page I am sending to my printer. You wrote .nomargin { margin:0 } to put in my css, which css you mean, I do not have any css file here just this fragment, or I do not understand something here ?

Comment: If you do not have a css file, just use the first suggestion: container.innerHTML = "<div style='margin:0;'>....."

Comment: Your first example does not work, I just have tried. I use WinJS printing and I need to add @page { margin:0cm;} rule to solve problem. My questions is also, how I can create external css and append to this fragment from my code above, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically create a `style` element and append it to the body. your css rules should be the internal content of this `style` element.

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .blue{ background-color:blue;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

Comment: When you use appendTo('head'); which head, since my fragment above is works on his own no any HTML page as container, I am sending that fragment to printer, is it possible to append directly to fragment, and without jquery, since WinJS does not allow using of jquery, actually allows but I am not using it :).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try to do this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>

        <!-- Inline Print CSS -->
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            .test {
                background-color: red;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- Inline Print CSS -->

        <!-- OR -->

        <!-- External Print CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file/print.css" media="print" >
        <!-- / External Print CSS -->

    </head>

        <!-- Injected Content by your Js script -->
        <div class="test">

        </div>
        <!-- / Injected Content by your Js script -->

    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Probably my understanding of the document fragment is wrong. I thought there is some method for creating body, html, styles and so on. For example document.createElement('html') or document.createElement('body'). One of the solution here according to your answer is to create  whole document as a string and create document from that string. In my case that is not possible since universal windows platform does not allow creating any content on that way because of security issue. All answer here are correct, but non of them works for me. Seems my questions is not well explained:)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, just create inside a css file (external one) the required rules, and call it in the html head. Then just add the class (according the one you created in your css file) to tthe div you are generating with the javascript code. Its cleaner and easy to use. Exactly as @Koby Douek said. :)

Comment: I updated my question above with one line var docsToPrint = MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(docHtml); which shows that there is no any other HTML page where I append my fragment. I just have send fragment like this to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

If so, then the best option you have is just add the css inline. something like:

```
container.innerHTML = "<div style='width:30px; height:30px; padding:0;'>" +
                        "Some content goes here" +
                  "</div>";
```

Comment: Yes I tried this, but it does not work. I need to add @page { margin:0cm;} to my page/fragment. Maybe my approach of creating fragment is wrong, since I have only div with some content inside. Is it possible to create whole page in this way. When I say whole page I think, body, html, style tag and so on, and then add my div inside ?

Comment: Yes, that the best way!!!!! :) and then yo can cal the css file on the html <head>. And then you just have to apply a class to the element.

Comment: That was my initial question. How to do that with document fragment ? Create html, body, add my div inside body and add style @page { margin:0cm;}. Can you please update your question with example ?